# merge multi-dimensional array and add default values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array like this and I would like to create a new array out of it and add in default values. The keys of the first array are fixed (00,01,02,03) but the keys in the secondary are dynamic values

```
Array
(  
[00] => Array
    (
        [KEY 1] => 100
        [KEY 2] => 50
        [KEY 3] => 30
    )

[01] => Array
    (
        [KEY 1] => 40
        [KEY 2] => 100
        [KEY 4] => 200
    )

[02] => Array
    (
        [KEY 1] => 30
        [KEY 2] => 40
        [KEY 3] => 30
    )

[03] => Array
    (
        [KEY 5] => 30
    )

 )
```

So my question is How can I turn the above array into something like this ?

```
Array
(  
[00] => Array
    (
        [KEY 1] => 10
        [KEY 2] => 50
        [KEY 3] => 30
        [KEY 4] => 0
        [KEY 5] => 0
    )

[01] => Array
    (
        [KEY 1] => 40
        [KEY 2] => 100
        [KEY 3] => 0
        [KEY 4] => 200
        [KEY 5] => 0
    )

[02] => Array
    (
        [KEY 1] => 30
        [KEY 2] => 40
        [KEY 3] => 30
        [KEY 4] => 0
        [KEY 5] => 0
    )

[03] => Array
    (
       [KEY 1] => 0
       [KEY 2] => 0
       [KEY 3] => 0
       [KEY 4] => 0
       [KEY 5] => 30
    )
```

)

I have been struggling all day and my head is getting tired. Can some one help ?

//HERE is the code i am using

contents of the CSV file

```
"00","KEY 1",100
"00","KEY 2",50
"00","KEY 3",30
"01","KEY 1",40
"01","KEY 2",100
"01","KEY 4",200
"02","KEY 1",30
"02","KEY 2",40
"02","KEY 3",30
"03","KEY 5",30
```

Here is the code

```
$csvFile='export (82).csv';


$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
 }
 foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    foreach ($line_of_text as $v) {
        if (!isset($val[$v]))
            $arr[$key][$v] = 0;
    }
 }
echo"<pre>";
 print_r($arr);
 echo"</pre>";
```

// CODE FOR CREATING THE Multi-dimensional array

```
$fp = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
$master = array();
while( $line = fgetcsv( $fp ) ) {

if( !isset( $master[$line[0]] ) )
    $master[$line[0]] = array();

if( !isset( $master[$line[0]][$line[1]] ) )
    $master[$line[0]][$line[1]] = 0;

$n = filter_var($line[2], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$master[$line[0]][$line[1]] += $n;
}
```

Comment: Are `KEY 1`, `KEY 2` ... strings or are they integers?

Comment: also post `print_r($csvFile)` in question

Comment: did you named your array to `$arr` ? I dont see you did

Comment: $csvFile just opens a csv file and the contents of the file are displayed in my question; Which array should be named to $arr ? i am confused

Comment: the multi dimensional array that you said in top of your question

Comment: and look at the update

Comment: yes i did that but i get this message llegal offset type in isset or empty in. I have added the code  i use to create the mutli-dimensional array

Comment: in my first comment I asked you how do you generate it, I meant keys by `it` . you said they are generated dynamically ... so HOW DO YOU GENERATE THE KEYS ????????????????

Comment: i misunderstood you, infact the keys are generated from the contents of the csv file. i posted the contents of my csv file and As you can see keys [00],[01,[02],[03] are the first elements that appear on each line of the csv file. KEY1,KEY2,etc are the second elements.

Answer (score 2):

If your input array is `$array`:

```
// merge inner arrays to get an array that has a value for every key
$merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);

// extract the keys from that array
$keys = array_keys($merged);

// build array that has value `0` for each key
$defaults = array_fill_keys($keys, 0);

// loop over the input array, adding values for missing keys
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
    $array[$key] += $defaults;
}
```

Note that for `array_merge` to give the desired result, the keys in the inner arrays need to be strings.

Comment: That's what I call an elegant solution. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
$defaults = [
    'KEY 1' => 0,
    'KEY 2' => 0,
    'KEY 3' => 0,
    'KEY 4' => 0,
    'KEY 5' => 0,
];

foreach ($values as &$v) {
    $v += $defaults;
}
unset($v);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
$keys = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");

$x = Array(
    Array( "A" => 10, "C" => 10),
    Array( "A" => 10, "D" => 20)
);

// Loop through $x
foreach($x as &$value){
    // Loop through the array 
    foreach($keys as $key){

        if(!in_array($key, array_keys($value))) {
            $value[ $key ] = 0;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($x);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { 
      [0]=> array(5) { 
          ["A"]=> int(10) 
          ["C"]=> int(10) 
          ["B"]=> int(0) 
          ["D"]=> int(0) 
          ["E"]=> int(0) 
      } 
      [1]=> &array(5) { 
          ["A"]=> int(10) 
          ["D"]=> int(20) 
          ["B"]=> int(0) 
          ["C"]=> int(0) 
          ["E"]=> int(0) 
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
            00 => array
                (
                'KEY1' => 100,
                'KEY2' => 50,
                'KEY3' => 30,
            ),
            01 => array
                (
                'KEY1' => 40,
                'KEY2' => 100,
                'KEY4' => 200,
            ),
            02 => array
                (
                'KEY1' => 30,
                'KEY2' => 40,
                'KEY3' => 30,
            )
            ,
            03 => array
                (
                'KEY5' => 30,
            ),
        );
        $csv = array_unique(explode(",", str_replace("\n", ",", file_get_contents("csv.csv"))));
        foreach ($csv as $key => $value) {
            $csv[$key] = str_replace("\"","", $value);
        }

        foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
            foreach ($csv as $v) {
                if (!isset($val[$v]))
                    $arr[$key][$v] = 0;
            }
        }
        print_r($arr);
```

Comment: thanks but the values "key1","key2",etc... are dynamic and i dont know in advance how many keys will be in that array. it may contain one, one hundred or a thousand keys

Comment: how do you generate it ?

Comment: the contents are from a csv file and this how it looks like      "00","KEY 1",100
"00","KEY 2",50
"00","KEY 3",30
"01","KEY 1",40
"01","KEY 2",100
"01","KEY 4",200
"02","KEY 1",30
"02","KEY 2",40
"02","KEY 3",30
"03","KEY 5",30                                                         and this is the code i use to put the csv contents into an array          $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
 while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
 }

Comment: given that the values of the array will be dynamic, do i need to declare the array the way you did in your code ? i have tried to declare $arr= array() but when i print_r the array, i get no data

Comment: no need to declare, can you post the exact code in your question so I can debug your problem?

Comment: just di it, when i use that code i get these 2 messages Undefined variable: arr 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: $csvFile just opens a csv file and the contents of the file are displayed in my question; Which array should be named to $arr ? i am confused